# Using for loop to take several columns from dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, error-handling, group

I'm inexperienced with for loops and try to write for loop in R for several columns from a df dataset. Each column I'm interested in has values from 1 to 15 or NA. "names" is a list of names of those columns:

```
>names

[1] "score"  "rate"   "asset"     "capital"  "earning"  "ast" "liquid"  "profit"  "assesment" "factor"
```

I want to replace their values with groups such as "1-5", "6-10", "11-15". I tried following code:

```
for (i in names){

    df <- mutate(df, i = 
                       ifelse(df$i >= 1 & df$i <= 5 , "1-5", 
                           ifelse(df$i >= 6 & df$i <= 10, "6-10",
                                ifelse(df$i >= 11 & df$i <= 15, "11-15",NA)))))
    }
```

But got an error:

```
Error: Column i must be length 2511 (the number of rows) or one, not 0
```

Could you please help/advice how to write such for loop and to solve this task.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to do this in `tidyverse`, use `across` to loop over the columns and use `case_when` instead of nested `ifelse`.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
   mutate(across(all_of(names), ~ case_when(.x >=1 & .x <=5 ~ "1-5",
              .x >= 6 & .x <= 10 ~  "6-10",
               .x >= 11 & .x <= 15 ~  "11-15")))
```

These can be done in a more easier way with `cut` or `findInterval`

```
df <- df %>%
      mutate(across(all_of(names), cut, breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 6, 11, 15, Inf)))
```

---

In the `for` loop there are multiple issues i.e. `i=` create a column named `i` and not the values in `i`.  In addition, `$i` will extract the `i` column if present and not the value of the column, use `[[` (here, both are not needed as we could convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`) or extract the column with `[[` from `.data`

```
for (i in names){

    df <- mutate(df, !!i := 
                       ifelse(.data[[i]] >= 1 & .data[[i]] <= 5 , "1-5", 
                           ifelse(.data[[i]] >= 6 & .data[[i]] <= 10, "6-10",
                             ifelse(.data[[i]] >= 11 & 
                .data[[i]] <= 15, "11-15",NA)))))
    }
```